# Custom Serializer and Deserializer with Jackson and Guice

Tags: rest, jersey, jackson, jax-rs, guice

I'm currently trying to add a custom serializer and deserializer for a REST API with Jackson Guice and Jersey. I have been trying to get them linked up however using an object mapper and a `JacksonJsonProvider`. How do I do this without adding annotation to the `User` class?

```
public class UserSerializer extends JsonSerializer<User>{

    @Override
    public void serialize(User value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        jgen.writeStartObject();
        jgen.writeStringField("name",value.getName());
        jgen.writeStringField("email",value.getEmail());
        jgen.writeStringField("first-name",value.getFirstName());
        jgen.writeStringField("last-name", value.getLastName());
        jgen.writeStringField("key",value.getKey().toString());
        jgen.writeObjectField("type",value.getType());
        jgen.writeEndObject();
    }
}
```

Here is my Guice config file, Guice servlet context listener.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
SimpleModule test = new SimpleModule(null, null);
test.addSerializer(User.class,new UserSerializer());
mapper.registerModule(test);
JacksonJsonProvider provider = new JacksonJsonProvider(mapper);
bind(JacksonJsonProvider.class).toInstance(provider);
```

However there seem to also be an error with `addSerializer` it red underlined.

Comment: Is there any particular reason to do not add annotations to your `User` class?

Comment: because then i would have to include the dependencies in another project. To use the annotation.

Comment: Make sure your Jackson major versions  are consistent, i.e. you aren't using both fasterxml and codehaus

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

The actual problem was that when i tried passing UserSerializer to addSerializer, i was constantly given an error. I had just realised that i imported the wrong JsonSerializer. I had imported databind.JsonSerializer and not map.JsonSerializer.

:)